# I need help memorizing Spanish idioms: is there a pattern between the words that I miss?

Tags: vocabulario, modismos

There are some idioms that I can't memorize because the way the phrase is in Spanish is unlike the English word. I can't find a logical pattern in why the phrases in Spanish are the way they are.

Can you help me find some patterns about these words that I can't memorize. Help me find why I can't memorize these words?

Is there a common reason that I can't remember these words? Can you spot some pattern among these words

- por màs que
- saber a
- salir a luz
- dar par en par
- cómo es eso?
- por poco
- a lo largo
- sí o sí

Comment: This question is very broad, asking about at least 8 phrases (and possibly more questions, depending on how you break up your question about memorization vs. meanings, etc).  I encourage you to ask one question per phrase/doubt you have. This will make it possible for us to provide much more specific answers, and will make the answers far more accessible to future visitors as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you've pointed out, many of these are idioms which by definition aren't intuitable by looking at the words that comprise them because they break patterns.

That said, many of the things you've listed aren't really idioms.

- *¿Cómo es eso?* is easily broken down and understood from its components (“How is that so?” or “How is that?” depending on whether *eso* is the subject or object)
- *saber* just takes the preposition *a* when used with verbs; English likewise has a number of verbs —sans predictable pattern— that require a preposition with verbs but not with nouns
- *sí o sí* translates word-to-word to English: “yes or yes”
- *par en par* is *two into two* or 100%, so *de par en par* means “completely”, “of 100%”, “at maximum”.

Since these expressions aren't really related, about all I can say is to work to memorize them and try to integrate them into your regular usage of the language and you'll eventually get them.

Comment: @Diego  Do you see nmnemonic for desde luego ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no pattern.

I'm afraid that is more or less the problem that non-native English speakers face with phrasal verbs. First, you need to memorize. After some time, your skill, experience and context of the sentence will allow you to understand the meaning of these idioms when you hear a new one for first time.

When learning English we always came across with these list with phrasal verbs. They are always really long lists, and we get warned they are never complete, since new phrasal verbs come up every day.

To a native Spanish speaker "Echar de menos" o "Ponerse al día" would make perfect sense, but they would have a hard time trying to explain you why those words together get that meaning, so I don't think you can extract patterns from these kind of idioms.